# Design Pattern for different interfaces

Tags: java, design-patterns

I've a question regarding the design patterns. I appreciate any kind of help.

I implemented the follwing interfaces and classes:

**IType** : has no methods because the implemented classes have different datatypes and different parameters.

```
public interface IType extends IType_1, IType_2 {}
```

**IType_1**

```
public interface IType_1 {
      public List<Object1> getDataType_1(List<String> list1, List<String> list2);   }
```

**Strategy_1**

```
public class Strategy_1 implements IType_1(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {

@Override
public List<Object1> getDataType_1() {
    return object1;
}   }
```

**IType_2**

```
public interface IType_2 {
      public List<Object2> getDataType_2(List<Object2> obj);   }
```

**Strategy_2**

```
public class Strategy_2 implements IType_2(List<Object2> obj) {

@Override
public List<Object2> getDataType_2() {
    return object2;
}   }
```

I tried to create the strategies by

**Strategy**

```
public class Strategy {

public Strategy() {}

public IType createStrategy(int strategyNo) {
    IType strategy = null;
    switch(strategyNo) {
    case 1: 
        strategy = (IType) new Strateg_1();
    case 2: 
        strategy = (IType) new Strateg_2();
    }
    return strategy;
}    }
```

... but it dosn't work.

The Strategies are not created when I run the class Strategy().

I get I an exception evertime I run the program.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method getDataType_1(List<String>, List<String>) is undefined for the type IType
```

The problem is IType extends IType_1 and IType_2. So the object Strategy doesn't really knows IType. And I don't know how to solve it to make Strategy knows IType.

What I want to achieve is to create Strategy_1 or Strategy_2 when I need it. After the Stategy is created I want to use its methods.

Thank you very much.

Comment: "... but it dosn't work. " what's exactly not working?

Comment: You should provide more Details. What do you want to accomplish and what does not work? Right now I don't see what you are trying to do.

Comment: The Strategies are not created when I run the class Strategy(). I got I an exception.

Comment: you need to define your method getDataType in interface which you are using, to get better help, explain to us what are you trying to achieve

Comment: You should look into the **Adapter** Pattern

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that is Strateg_1 is NOT a IType

IType is a IType_1, but IType_1 is NOT an IType

IType is a IType_2, but IType_2 is NOT an IType

You could do instead :

```
public interface IType_1 extends IType {....}


public interface IType_2 extends IType {....}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I did it already. The problem is when IType extends IType_1 and IType_2. So the object Strategy doesn't really knows IType. And I don't know how to solve it to make Strategy knows IType.

Comment: If Strategy class can't find the IType interface, you probably need an import statement. Are the two in the same package?

Comment: Yes they are in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

1. this is not working,  what error have you got?
2. have a look here:

   `public class Strategy_1 implements IType_1(List<String> list1, List<String> list2)`

   this line is invalid because this `(List<String> list1, List<String> list2)` should not be there
3. you can't cast `Strateg_1` to `IType` as `Strateg_1` does not implements it

i suggest you to get rid of `IType_1` and `IType_2`  if possible, and have interface

```
public interface IType<OBJECT> { 
    public List<OBJECT> getDataType(List<String> list1, List<String> list2); 
 }
```

and implementantations

```
public class Strategy_1 implements IType<Object1>{
...
}

public class Strategy_2 implements IType<Object2>{
...
}
```

Comment: I get this error:                                              Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method getDataType_1(List<String>, List<String>) is undefined for the type IType

Comment: First of all thank you :). If I do this the problem will be that the classes Strategy_1 and Strategy_2  have to implement all the methods of IType<OBJECT>  and I don't want this. Strategy_1 needs to implement only a specific method from  IType<OBJECT>  not all of them. Same thing with Strategy_2